# Milkman Ad Mob framework in starling problems

Tags: android, admob

We recently implemented the Milkman Ad Mob framework to use it in our app, made in Starling, and we are experiencing some problems in android platform:

1. At Low End devices we are experiencing a crash, it happens one second after the Ad Mob appear. After this crash the app restarts.
2. On some devices (tested on MotoG, Galaxy S3, Nexus 4) the X close button appears and then disappears complicating usability.

Can you help me?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I tried:
1. to stop Starling before Ads 
2. Different Adobe Air versions (It works on 3.8 but IOs doens't support it, so it doesn't work for me)
3. Some other ANEs

Answer (score 0):

(Milkman Games Here):

Usually this means you are using direct mode (stage3D) but not handling context changes correctly on Android.

If you are using Starling, this means you need to be using the latest version of the Starling framework, and you should be setting handleLostContext to true:

```
Starling.handleLostContext=true;
```

You also should ensure that your application handles NativeApplication's state events by properly stopping and starting the starling context, i.e.:

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.ACTIVATE, onStageActive);
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.DEACTIVATE, onStageDeactivate);


/** Stage Activated */
unction onStageActive(e:flash.events.Event):void
{
    starling.start();
}

/** Stage Deactivated */
function onStageDeactivate(e:flash.events.Event):void
{
    starling.stop(true);
}
```

If you are using stage3D without starling, you need to ensure that your application correctly stops/starts rendering of stage3D in response to these events and handles CONTEXT3D create/loss events appropriately for Android.